# Image url changed for same image source in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I used an image in portfolio page as well as in slider.

In the portfolio page the image is rendering correctly with the url **/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/em-hospital-2.png?resize=300%2C223 300w, /wp-content/uploads/2015/08/em-hospital-2.png?w=498 498w** .

In the slider, the image url (**/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/em-hospital-2.png?fit=1%2C1**) get changed and is not rendering.

I am not able to understand why **fit=1%2C1** added at the end.

Answer (score 1):

if you use featured image in slider and on portfilo page than can you please try this

```
<?php 
$thumb_id = 25;
$url = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $thumb_id );
?>
<img src="<?php echo $url ?>"/>
```

Here `$thumb_id = 25;` Is Post ID you can `replace 25 with your post ID`